# Matching based on annotation values using aspectj

Tags: aspectj

I have a class and an annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AnnotateMethod
{
  public abstract boolean value();
}

class AAA{
@AnnotateMethod(value=true)
void method()
{


}

@AnnotateMethod(value=false)
    void method1()
    {


    }

    void method2()
    {


    }
    }
```

I want to write an aspectj pointcut that will capture all methods that have AnnotateMethod annotation with value=true. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(anMethod) && if()")
public static boolean annotatedMethod(final AnnotateMethod anMethod) {
    return anMethod.value();
}
```

Defines a pointcut over all method executions which have your annotation and before execution of the advise checks whether said annotation has value == true.

No guarantee for immediate runnability as I'm working off memory here but it should be good to go. ;)

Comment: how to specify it without the @Pointcut syntax in traditional pointcut syntax?